Are all normed vector spaces over $\mathbb{R}^2 \cup \mathbb{R}^3$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^3$?
Sometimes real world problems present finite sequences of real numbers of different lengths - e.g. audio signals, etc.  One naive way to compute distances between these sequences is to simply pad the shorter sequence with 0s so that the two sequences have the same length $l$ and use one of the available norms and the usual vector operations in $\mathbb{R}^l$.
Is it the case that this is actually the only option up to isomorphism?  Are there other norms and vector operations on $\mathbb{R}^2 \cup \mathbb{R}^3$ than just the ones on $\mathbb{R}^3$?

What you are really doing is mapping $\mathbb{R}^2$ into a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$, for instance, $(a,b)\mapsto (a,b,0)$. Thus, you are really just working with $\mathbb{R}^3$ and use $\mathbb{R}^2$ as a subspace. However, the grand ambient space in which you live is $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Although this approach may be fancier than you'd like, it is decisive:
There's a theorem in basic functional analysis that all finite-dimensional real (or complex) vectorspaces have a unique topology. This does not quite imply the comparability of norms, but, meanwhile, there is a theorem (that I myself know from algebraic number theory) that all "norms" are "equivalent", in the sense of comparability up to constants...
There is another uniqueness result about a topological vector space topology on an ascending union of finite-dimensional spaces (a "strict colimit")...

I'm 110% about free/cheap results from general theories - but I'm just a curious engineer who is a very mediocre mathematician. :)
